INTN Token Scam - Cannot sell it back
I recently bought some INTN tokens on Sushiswap on this address:
https://www.sushi.com/bsc/swap?token0=NATIVE&token1=0xc2F2aa856b78fdE3Da3CA3999d23011525727736
As you can see the token address as well. I cannot sell it back anymore. I've done some research that it's a scam token, but unfortunately I learned that too late after buying over 1000 USDT.
Does someone have an idea how I can swap it with USDT or any other coin for that matter?
I'm very sad and mad at myself.

This question is similar to: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've done some research about it, and unfortunately there's no solution for that, our money is gone, it's a honeypot. Me and one of my friends also lost money on this INTN fraud, so it's going to be a harsh lesson for us.

Thank you Behrouz. What a mistake. Expensive lesson. That motherf***er Mahan Sepehri. How can he still continue. He's claiming that if we buy 2 BNBs right now, we can release our assets. LOL. And there are other people on Twitter who claim to recover it if I paid 250 USDT hahaha. These are their X IDs: @ Klaus__Dev1, @ EugeneDenETH, and @ derekcrypt
